# Uploading image on facebook page

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to upload image onto facebook using graph API. Here is what i am doing

```
Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.test);
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    largeIcon.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putByteArray("object_attachment", byteArray);// object attachment must be either byteArray or bitmap image
    bundle.putString("message", "some message here");
    bundle.putString("access_token", "my_access_token_for_page");
    bundle.putBoolean("published", true);
    GraphRequest graphRequest = new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            "{page_id}/photos",
            bundle,
            HttpMethod.POST,
            new GraphRequest.Callback() {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse graphResponse) {

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
    graphRequest.executeAsync();
```

But unfortunately i am getting this error

```
{Response:  responseCode: 404, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 404, errorCode: 803, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: {page_id}}}
```

I have no idea whats going wrong.
I have generated the access token of the page using GraphAPIExplorer.

Please help me on this.
Thanx in advance.

Comment: You did replace `{page_id}` with an _actual_ page id, right …?

Comment: Yes i did replace page_id and access_token :)

Comment: You are passing `AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()` to the GraphRequest, and that is the _user_ access token of the current app user.

Comment: So i have to pass the access token of the page instead of AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() right?

When i debug it this is returning null

Comment: I don’t think you can just pass a string as first parameter to the GraphRequest constructor - but you should be able to pass just NULL (or something like that, whatever the equivalent in Android is), then it should take the access token you are passing via the parameters bundle.

Comment: I passed null as the first parameter now i am getting this error

{Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: -1, errorCode: -1, errorType: null, errorMessage: could not construct request body}}